# Allow browse the directory listings and deny download without being login

Tags: .htaccess, directory

Via an .htaccess directive how to allow visitors to browse the default directory listings and redirect visitors to a login page PHP if they try to download file without being login?

I use Apache and PHP login form with sessions

**EDIT:** I think I have found a solution with **`mod_auth_form`** and **`mod_session`**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***I solved the problem.*** It's really nice the help we may not receive here, thank you.

Comment: I'm glad you found a solution. Why don't you share it for future visitors?